# Automatically adding a bluetooth device in Windows 8

Tags: batch-file, windows-8, bluetooth

I had made a batch file a ways back to toggle between having my sound go through my computer speakers or my soundbar. I want to still do this, but am now connecting via bluetooth. I found some bluetooth command line tools, and now have a batch file:

```
@ECHO OFF
if exist toggle.txt goto :2
btpair -u
C:\NIRCMD\NIRCMDC setdefaultsounddevice "CompSpeak" 1
C:\NIRCMD\NIRCMDC setdefaultsounddevice "CompSpeak" 2

echo toggle>>toggle.txt

exit
:2
btpair -n"[Samsung] AirTrack" -p0000
C:\NIRCMD\NIRCMDC setdefaultsounddevice "Headphones" 1
C:\NIRCMD\NIRCMDC setdefaultsounddevice "Headphones" 2

del toggle.txt /q

exit
```

The only thing is, when I try and pair the bluetooth device using this command, Windows 8 will pop up this:
[image: Popup]

If I click on this, it takes me away from my desktop and shows the progress bar of me pairing and it works. If I don't press it, the command will error out. It's only a small inconvenience, but I wanted to check to see if there is a way of skipping this trivial popup (Either in the command line, or my changing the Windows settings somewhere to do something like an autoplay equivalent for a bluetooth device).